# Convert unicode to xml string

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I have  a unicode string, defined as

```
data= u'<project> <DataRuleDefinitions> <DataRuleDefinition name="dummy_def">
 <ExecutableRule name="rule_dummy_def" excludeDuplicates="false" 
  folder="14_A_Loan_Loss_Projections;All"><Bindings> <Binding var="field"><Columnname="CLL_IA_SNAPSHOT.prod_files.prod_files."CLL_201706.csv".AccrualStatusChangeDate"/> </Binding> </Bindings> </ExecutableRule> </DataRuleDefinition> 
 </DataRuleDefinitions> </project>'
```

I did try to convert it to xml using the following idea:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.fromstring(data)
```

But I am encountering the following error:
         `ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 326`

Can I  kindly get help to rectify this error and convert this unicode to  xml?

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. Specifically, this fragment: `<Columnname="CLL_IA_SNAPSHOT.prod_files.prod_files."CLL_201706.csv".AccrualStatusChangeDate"/> ` isn't valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues and **neither** appears to be an issue with unicode to XML conversion. The issue as mentioned by your error is poorly formed XML, causing a `ParseError`.

The problem is with the following line of XML:

```
<Columnname="CLL_IA_SNAPSHOT.prod_files.prod_files."CLL_201706.csv".AccrualStatusChangeDate"/>
```

Element names are not allowed to have an equal sign in them, assign this data to the val attribute (the attribute name can be anything):

```
<Columnname val="CLL_IA_SNAPSHOT.prod_files.prod_files."CLL_201706.csv".AccrualStatusChangeDate"/>
```

There is still an issue. Quote around **val**, but also quotes around **val's** value. We can remove these, escape them, or use a different quote encapsulation:

```
<Columnname val="CLL_IA_SNAPSHOT.prod_files.prod_files.'CLL_201706.csv'.AccrualStatusChangeDate"/>
```

Now you should have no issues. If you would like to check that your XML is good, you can [use an online XML pretty printer](http://xmlbeautifier.com/), of which [there are many](https://www.google.com/search?q=xml+pretty+print+online). They should tell you if you have poorly formed XML. Good luck!